# ajax calender extender months don't localize please help

Tags: ajax, sharepoint-2010

In sharepoint site i've webpart with ajax calender extender .Today in calender localized but not months and days .
In script Manager i enabled
EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true"

Added resource .dll in to bin of site.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I was also having problem in Asp.net site. Today was localized but Months and Days not.

Finally it turned out that I was calling a script using `registerClientScriptBlock` and at the end of function name there was no '`;`' .That caused culture variable to be ignored.

Putting '`;`' at the end of function solved the problem.

I was able to find this issue using *firebug*.